# TitaniumStudio - Android SDK

Tags: android, macos, mobile, sdk, titanium

I've tried every possible way I can think of and followed every forum list I can find, still to no avail.  I'm trying to get the Android SDK to be recognized by TitaniumStudio.  I installed in by going through the folders and running it that way, I've tried the command line option, I've installed it through Eclipse (which it works in) but TitaniumStudio STILL will not recognize it.  I've reinstalled TitaniumStudio, that didn't work.

Key Points:

- Everything is up to date
- I'm working on Mac OSX 10.6.8
- I know of Terminal and what it can do, but don't know Unix commands
- The above is probably significant because somewhere in a forum someone mentioned changing the PATH for the sdk to read the /tools and /platform-tools folders using the /.bash_profile (I think that's what it's called, correct me if I'm wrong there) but when I tried to run the command via terminal to create an AVD (android create avd -n android_sdk -t 2 (android_sdk being the AVD name and 2 to point to the android-4 platform)), i get the following error:

> -bash: android: command not found

Please help me with some insight into this "-bash" and what that is and how to fix this annoying problem! >.<

---

EDIT: I've gotten it to a point where I now get the following error when I try to send (android create avd -n android_sdk -t 2) through terminal:

> Valid ABIs: no ABIs.
>
> Error: This platform has more than one ABI.  Please specify one using --abi.

What the heck does that mean and what's an ABI?? o.O

Answer (score 1):

Run tools/android, It'll fire up a "Android SDK Manager" where you would see various platforms listed and the ABI's for those platforms underneath them. For example when I fire up my "Android SDK Manager", I see Android 4.0 (API 14) and then underneath it is "ARM EABI v7a System Image". Check this package  and install it. Confirm that ABI's are indeed listed by running the command "android list targets".

Comment: That helps but what is ABI?

Answer (score 0):

Remember to start a new terminal when you are making changes to .bash_profile or .bashrc files. Failing to do so, would lead to errors like you are experiencing because the changes isn't loaded in, and the new PATHs and all the programs there isn't available to you.

With that being said, you need to add the folder with binary programs to your path, you can verify that the path is loaded in with the following command:

```
echo $PATH
```

Which gives me this on Snow Leopard:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Setting a path can be difficult in OSX because it seems like they have changed this behavior quite a bit between releases.

Look here for a more detailed answer about setting path variables: https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard

There is also a description here on how to get Snow Leopard to read the user supplied .bashrc in the home-dir: http://kaspergrubbe.dk/2011/enable-bashrc-on-osx-snow-leopard-and-lion/

Comment: Any chance you can address the problem above that I put in the 'EDIT'? :/